# How to change php.ini memory_limit per folder when php is set up on FASTCGI API

Tags: php, fastcgi, memory-limit

Hi I have a site that requires extra memory allocation for an image upload system. On the development server changing the memory_limit is not an issue but on the live server php has been set up using FASTCGI as the API and not Apache. This now causes me a problem as I can not change the setting using any of the following. Has anyone come across this before and can offer a solution.

Methods already tried:
ini_set('memory_limit', '250M') in the script file
.htaccess php_value memory_limit 250M
php.ini added to the directory holding the script file memory_limit = 250M
php.ini copy of whole file with memory limit changed

Many thanks

Comment: Ask your hoster/server admin. Maybe you are not even _allowed_ to change that value.

Comment: I have full access to altering whatever I wish on the server so this is not the issue.